# Jquery .html() not working - selecting html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have code like this:

```
$cena = $(element) > $('.main_paket_cena').attr('name');
alert($cena);
```

So I am selecting an element inside `element` which has class `main_paket_cena`

My html for this looks like this:

```
<div class='main_paket $firstClassActive' onclick='toggleMenuSelection(this)'>
    <p class='main_paket_kolicina'>$kolicina $jm</p>
    <p class='main_paket_cena' name='testing'>$cena din</p>
</div>
```

so instead of `testing` it returns me `true`.

I have tried using `.html()` to see what will it display and again it displays `true` but if I go with code like this:

```
$(element) > $('.main_paket_cena').html("Some HTML");
```

It changes html of all elements with class `main_paket_cena`

Answer (score 6):

> So I am selecting element inside `element` which has class `main_paket_cena`

This is not the case. Your use of the `>` operator is performing a 'greater than' comparison of the jQuery objects. This is why the result is a boolean value - `true` in your case.

If you want to select one element within another, use `find()`:

```
var cena = $(element).find('.main_paket_cena').attr('name');
console.log(cena);
```

Comment: Was trying it all time but instead of `var` I used `$` and it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: @Pacijent If you want to name the variable with `$`, you can write `var $cena = ...`.

Comment: Note that I remove the `$` prefix from the variable name as that's used for denoting a variable which holds a jQuery object, which isn't the case here, as it holds a simple string.